# sequelize error: missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql, node.js, foreign-keys, migration, constraints

**20181005120552-create-order-detail.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('OrderDetails', {
      orderDetailId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      orderId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'Orders',
          key: 'orderId'
        }
      },
      productName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      count: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      orderDetailPrice: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'Orders',
          key: 'totalPrice'
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('OrderDetails');
  }
};
```

**20181005120522-create-order**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface
    .createTable('Orders', {
      orderId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'userId'
        }
      },
      orderDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      totalPrice: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      orderState: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      shippingNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      basicAddress: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      detailAddress: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      telNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      phoneNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Orders');
  }
};
```

When i executed script `sequelize db:migrate`, previous migration is without errors executed. in this level it returns error. I don't know how can i resolve this problem i guess it has something wrong.

> ERROR: Failed to add the foreign key
>   constraint. Missing index for
>   constraint 'orderdetails_ibfk_2' in
>   the referenced table 'orders'

This is error message. I wanna connect files `OrderDetails.orderDetailPrice` and `Orders.totalPrice`.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know about sequelize but in mysql you would have to create orders before order_details.

Comment: creating tables are automatic so that i can't control that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giordano,

I defined this way the code is below. Let me know why this code can be migrated? **primary key** and **unique key** both keys are written though..

**create-order-detail.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('OrderDetails', {
          (...),
          productName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
            // allowNull: false
            unique: true
          },
          count: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
          },
          orderDetailPrice: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            // references: {
            //     model: 'Orders',
            //     key: 'totalPrice'
            // }
          },
          createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          },
          updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          }
        })
      .then(() => {
        queryInterface.addConstraint('OrderDetails', ['orderDetailPrice'], {
          type: 'foreign key',
          references: {
            name: 'orderdetails_ibfk_2',
            table: 'Orders',
            field: 'totalPrice'
          },
        })
      })
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('OrderDetails');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As reported [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/311), it seems that Sequelize has some issues with references to **composite keys**.

However, by exploiting the Sequelize query execution you can workaround you problem. In you case you can perform the following mysql query:

```
ALTER TABLE `db_test`.`OrderDetails` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_order_detailes_orders` 
FOREIGN KEY (`orderId` , `orderDetailId`) 
REFERENCES `db_test `.`orders`(`orderId` , `totalPrice`);
```

So your **create-order-detail** migration file becomes the following:

```
    'use strict';
    module.exports = {
        up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            return queryInterface.createTable('OrderDetails', {
                orderDetailId: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    allowNull: false,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                },
                orderId: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    allowNull: false,
                },
                productName: {
                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    allowNull: false,
                },
                count: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                },
                orderDetailPrice: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    allowNull: false,
                },
                createdAt: {
                    allowNull: false,
                    type: Sequelize.DATE,
                },
                updatedAt: {
                    allowNull: false,
                    type: Sequelize.DATE,
                },
            })
                .then(() => {
                    return queryInterface.sequelize.query('ALTER TABLE `OrderDetails` ADD ' +
                        'CONSTRAINT `fk_order_details_orders` FOREIGN KEY (`orderId`, `orderDetailPrice`) REFERENCES ' +
                        'Orders(`orderId`, `totalPrice`)');
                });
        },
        down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            return queryInterface.dropTable('OrderDetails', null);
        },
    };
```

Comment: resolved this issue by promises in migration file **create-order-detail**. i inserted the code .addConstraint() what is the different with your code?

Comment: Please past you code otherwise it's difficult for me to give you an answer. For example, how have you defined a constraint for a composite key?